# How to pass the argument using argparse in xml format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm Trying to pass the argument as CLI,and it have two commands SHOW and CREATE all i want to know is how to pass the command in xml format like my command will be like

```
$ program.py <CREATE ID=12334>   # where CREATE is cmd and 'ID=' is fixed constant and integer has to be passed as input.
# matches the pattern if it is the valid pattern then
$ <pattern>valid</pattern>
#else should print <pattern> invalid </pattern>
```

its a wrong code but i'm just showing the idea about the code.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('<CREATE ID=>', '--option', help="Best option name here.")
args = parser.parse_args()


if args.option == '<CREATE ID= 123 >':
    create()
elif args.option == '<SHOW ID= 123':
    show()
else:
    print("Didn't make it!")
```

i expect the output like

```
$ program.py <CREATE ID= (input) COLOR=GREEN>
  if the operation has been successful:
$ <MESSAGE>OK</MESSAGE>

$ program.py <SHOW ID=(input)>

  <SHOW ID= 1>\n
  //some more functions
  </SHOW>\n
```

Comment: The format of your arguments is bizarre, is there a reason why you cannot pass the arguments in a standard way? `program.py --command create --id 123` for example

Comment: yes, but i wanted them like that..is that possible in sys.arg?

Comment: Nothing is impossible but you are making things very complicated for yourself. If you insist on XML input then put it in a file instead.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the shell (`bash`) or `argparse` handles this `xml` format in any special way.  It's just a string or list of strings.

A simpler script:

```
import argparse, sys

print(sys.argv)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('option')   # 'option' is the 'dest'
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if 'CREATE' in args.option:
    print('creating')
elif 'SHOW' in args.option:
    print('showing')
else:
    print('else')
```

test runs:

```
2333:~/mypy$ python3 stack57237963.py "<CREATE ID=123>"
['stack57237963.py', '<CREATE ID=123>']
Namespace(option='<CREATE ID=123>')
creating
2337:~/mypy$ python3 stack57237963.py "<SHOW ID=123>"
['stack57237963.py', '<SHOW ID=123>']
Namespace(option='<SHOW ID=123>')
showing
2337:~/mypy$ python3 stack57237963.py "<FLUB ID=123>"
['stack57237963.py', '<FLUB ID=123>']
Namespace(option='<FLUB ID=123>')
else
2337:~/mypy$ python3 stack57237963.py <CREATE ID=123>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

I don't know `bash` well enough to understand this error.

Here's the split that I expect `bash` to do:

```
2337:~/mypy$ python3 stack57237963.py CREATE ID=123
['stack57237963.py', 'CREATE', 'ID=123']
usage: stack57237963.py [-h] option
stack57237963.py: error: unrecognized arguments: ID=123
```

This line produces an error.

```
parser.add_argument('<CREATE ID=>', '--option', help="Best option name here.")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack57237963.py", line 6, in <module>
    parser.add_argument('<CREATE ID=>', '--option', help="Best option name here.")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1333, in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_optional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1464, in _get_optional_kwargs
    raise ValueError(msg % args)
ValueError: invalid option string '<CREATE ID=>': must start with a character '-'
```

With `--option` you are telling `argparse` that this is a `optional`, a flagged argument.  So it expects the other parameter to all have the flag prefix, '-'.

I could drop the '--option':

```
parser.add_argument('<CREATE ID=>', help="Best option name here.")
```

in which case it takes that string as the argument `dest`:

```
Namespace(option='ID=123', **{'<CREATE ID=>': 'CREATE'})
```

The first parameters to `add_argument` must be either optional's flag strings (which start with '-'), or a parameter `dest` (for a positional).

Comment: The bash error is because there is no file name after the unquoted output redirection operator `>`

Comment: Thanks, I don't use that bash redirect often enough to automatically interpret it as such.  It highlights the fact that we have to play by the shell's rules.